# Fetching one's old Facebook status messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, status

I want to fetch one's old Facebook status. I have written the code for the same but it looks like it is not working for me. The steps that I have followed are as follows:

1. First I use the below API to seek the code from Facebook (by prompting user to log in to the Facebook page)
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxyy&redirect_uri=http://xxyy/home.aspx&scope=publish_stream,read_stream";
2. Then I seek the AccessToken by passing the code obtained in the above point to the below api as:
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxy&redirect_uri=http://xxyy/home.aspx&client_secret=xxyy&code=zzz"
3. Now there is a problem. I am not able to understand which API I need to use to fetch the old status of the logged in user. I guess I have the access token which is the key to fetching the info. But I am not able to find the relevant API.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use FQL.

```
//PHP example:
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. '/fql?q=fql?q=SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid=me()'
. '&' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
```

Comment: Is FQL the only way to retrieve the old status message? Also... how do i mention the date if at all I need to fetch the status for a particular date?

Answer (score 1):

The graph API and "post" feed is what you need. I don't usually do this but I need my old statuses!

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me  for fetching Facebook Conversation:

```
String s = facebook.request("me/inbox");
System.out.println("Message...."+s);
```